# Best way to hide a row with contols of a grid view at runtime but controls should be enabled?

Tags: asp.net

I want to hide a row with contols of a grid view at runtime but controls should be enabled.

I have a grid view which consists a checkbox, 2 textboxes and 1 dropdown list control for every row and i want that on a particular condition that grid view row should not be displayed but internally these controls should be enabled.

Comment: apply css class or style that includes display:none

Answer (score 2):

Set the row's css style to display: none.
See here: [Selectively apply css to a row in a gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208038/selectively-apply-css-to-a-row-in-a-gridview)

Comment: It's just making the row highlighted not doing the expected as asked by OP.

Comment: That question just tells you how to apply a css class. You can use the same technique to set the row's css style to display: none.

Comment: by doing this, will not show the row controls. Everything will be hidden in this scenario.

Comment: thanks @cbp its working.. i did "e.Row.Style.Add("display", "none");"