# Styling a GridView's rows and cells with CSS

Tags: css, gridview, webforms

I want to use CSS to format my GridView rows.

I've set up my GridView in the aspx like so:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

I set and bind the data source in the code-behind by calling a method to get my data set from a data access layer.

However, because I set the datasource programmatically, the rows and cells have no id attributes.

How can you use CSS to style and format those rows and cells?

This is the HTML generated currently:

```
<div>
    <table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ContentPlaceHolderHome_GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Date</th><th scope="col">Project</th><th scope="col">Amount</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>1/1/2011 12:00:00 AM</td><td>MY COMPANY</td><td>1000.99</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>2/1/2011 12:00:00 AM</td><td>ABC Company</td><td>1001.99</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>1/3/2011 12:00:00 AM</td><td>MY COMPANY</td><td>1002.99</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>4/1/2011 12:00:00 AM</td><td>MY COMPANY</td><td>1003.99</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use selector like this

```
  <style>
    #ContentPlaceHolderHome_GridView1 td {
     background : #ccc;
   }
  </style>
```

Comment: is there a way to access individual cells in the table. For instance what if i wanted to change all the cells in the column to a color or just a random cell a certain color

Comment: you can use css3 pseudo-selector (which means not supported by IE8-7-6) [:nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple ways you can apply row style to a gridview.

1) In the code behind you can apply styles and such on [RowDatabound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208038/selectively-apply-css-to-a-row-in-a-gridview).

2) In between the gridview tags you can use the:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"> 
<rowstyle CssClass="myClass" />
<alternatingrowstyle CssClass="myClass" />
</asp:GridView>
```

See this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowstyle.aspx) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your grid to include each column. Apply the `ItemStyle-CssClass` attribute.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="fooGrid" >
    <Columns> 
     <asp:BoundField  ItemStyle-CssClass="fooBarBat"  
                      DataField="MyDataFieldName" HeaderText="Bar" />     
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the properties window to set the CssClass property to use a class from a CSS. Or you can simple set the fonts and colors instead using the same properties window.

[image: GridView Properties]

Answer (score 0):

in gridview you can set attributes called HeaderCSSClass and CSSClass(not sure about the names, could be wrong. google them).