# How to bind gridview with data by using loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written code like below lines of code

```
   protected void grdView_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LicenceBL lbl = new LicenceBL(0);
        DataSet lds = new DataSet();
        lbl.FetchForEdit(lds, LicenseType);
        foreach (GridViewRow row in grdView.Rows)
        {
            Label lblJurisdiction = row.FindControl("lblJurisdiction") as Label;
            TextBox txtDateIssued = row.FindControl("txtEffectiveDate") as TextBox;
            TextBox txtDateExpiration = row.FindControl("txtExpirationDate") as TextBox;
            TextBox txtLicenseNumber = row.FindControl("txtLicenseNumber") as TextBox;
            for (int i = 0; i < lds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                txtLicenseNumber.Text = lds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["LicenceNumber"].ToString();
            }
        }


    }
```

I want to bind grid view without using datasource property of gridview. The above code is not working...

Let's Suppose lds contains data like

=====================================================

LicenceNumber - LicenceIssueDate

123   - 12/10/2014

345   - 12/1/2013

=====================================================

Similarily Grid will also contain the data

=====================================================

LicenceNumber - LicenceIssueDate

123   - 12/10/2014

345   - 12/1/2013

=====================================================

Here is grid view's design

```
                        <asp:GridView ID="grdView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDataBinding="grdView_DataBinding" BorderWidth="0" runat="server" CssClass="table">
                            <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="License Number">
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtLicenseNumber" style="padding:12px 5px;" runat="server" />
                                       <br />
                                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ValReqLN" Display="Dynamic" runat="server"
                                    ErrorMessage="License Number cannot be Blank." ControlToValidate="txtEffectiveDate"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                   </ItemTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>

                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Effective Date">
                                   <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEffectiveDate" style="padding:12px 5px;" placeholder="(mm/dd/yyyy)" CssClass="datepiker" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>

                        </asp:GridView>
```

Please help!!!

Comment: What should your output look like?  Right now it should output the last row's "LicenseNumber" field.

Comment: I want to bind gridview programically because I have to give many conditions inside gridview's rows according to business logic in order to display data in the gridview. Here I want to bind gridview by dataset lds.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Can you mock up the output and paste a screen shot to your question?

Comment: "not working" depends what you are expecting. Are you getting an error? What you are trying to do, please add that in your question to let others help you ;) Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Basically I want bind gridview by using loop. We usually bind gridview using DataSource like GridView1,DataSource = lds but here I want to bind grid view programically... Please help me !!!

Comment: So what you really want is a parent-detail hierarchy in your grid... You are going to have to manually databind the outer `GridView` as you have done, and then databind an inner `GridView` to `lds.Tables[0].Rows`

Comment: Why don't use datareader then?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you not use `datasource` property ? you said: "i want to bind gridview `programically` because I have to give many conditions inside gridview's rows according to business logic in order to display data in the gridview.

Here is how you can do that:

**Code behind:**

```
protected void grdView_DataBinding(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
    DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
    if (drv["txtLicenseNumber"].ToString().ToLower() == "abc")
    {
       //Apply business logic here on each row, hide/show etc
        e.Row.CssClass = "highlighted";
    }
   }    
}
```

Read more here on:

[Dynamically change GridView Cell value using RowDataBound event in ASP.Net using C# and VB.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-change-GridView-Cell-value-using-RowDataBound-event-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

[Selectively apply css to a row in a gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208038/selectively-apply-css-to-a-row-in-a-gridview)

Comment: Will that ever go in to this statement? 
if (drv["txtLicenseNumber"].ToString().ToLower() == "ABC") .  I think you meant .ToUpper() or "abc" ?